# How to detect if an image is a texture or a pattern-based image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I have a question regarding computer vision; seems to be a general question but anyways, just wondering if you might have a clue. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to distinguish texture images (or photos with repetitive patterns) between whatnot, say realistic photos? The patterns could have exact repetitions, or just have major similarity. Actually I'm trying to see given an image if, it is possible to detect it is a texture or a pattern-based image, and that in real-time maybe?

For instance these three are considered textures in our context:

http://www.bigchrisart.com/sites/default/files/video/TR_Texture_RockWall.jpg
http://www.colourbox.com/preview/4440275-144135-seamless-geometric-op-art-texture.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: The first link was updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot open your first image. I implemented the Fourier transform on your second one, and you can see frequency responses at specific points:

[image]

You can further process the image by extract the local maximum of the magnitude, and they share the same distance to the center (zero frequency). This may be considered as repetitive patterns.

Regarding the case that patterns share major similarity instead of repetitive feature, it is hard to tell whether the frequency magnitude still has such evident response. It depends on how the pattern looks like.

Another possible approach is the auto-correlation on your image.

Comment: umm, Thanks for the good info! I've updated the first image. One thing that I'm not familiar with that much is the role of FFT in this context; how transforming into a frequency domain helps?

Comment: @user3204706, spatial info corresponding to frequency info. For a image with highly periodic pattern in spatial domain, it will also contain highly periodic frequency distribution in frequency domain is also periodic, and also conjugate. Conjugate means, if you have the frequency of u+iv in 2D domain, you must also have u-iv, -u+iv, and -u-iv.